# Fastest way to achieve DHCP on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-protocols, dhcp

**Motivation:** I run wpa_supplicant without a network managing tool because I don't want to force new DHCP leases when my old ones work. This way I can get onto an old network very fast (as soon as wpa_supplicant establishes the lower network layers) if the DHCP lease has not expired.

**Problem:** But when the DHCP lease has expired, or if my IP address is from another network, I do need to call upon DHCP. I currently use dhclient, but dhcpcd is another option here. The problem is, even though these DHCP clients run in the background, they don't automatically realize that I need a new IP address, since I've got an old, invalid one.

**Question:** Is there a way to very quickly determine if I'm in need of DHCP? E.g. as a reaction to wpa_supplicant or as a response to contacting the standard gateway and realizing a connection isn't available. I can easily run `sudo dhclient wlan0`, and it gives me the address in one second. But what can I do to automate this process, when necessary?

Making unnecessary DHCP requests is not out of the question, but flooding the DHCP server is.

**Elaborate question:** For those of you who use wpa_supplicant directly, how do you DHCP?

Comment: Perhaps you can use Network Manager's [nm-online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/nm-online.1.html) tool to determine if the link is up.

Comment: What's wrong with renewing a DHCP lease when you return to a network? Is it really that much slower?

Comment: What's wrong: My school actually has too few wifi NAT addresses at the start of the year! So owning a DHCP lease is good stuff. I actually only know that NetworkManager is sometimes a few seconds slower than plain wpa_supplicant, and I don't know if it's DHCP, but I figured that I can quickly infer if I need it (e.g. by sending a packet that requires an IP address).

Comment: Whenever I run dhcpcd to connect to a wireless router after being connected to it, I usually get the same IP address back. So I expect it is confirming an existing lease rather than giving a new lease. So if you have a lease already, I don't think you'd lose it by renegotiating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run dhcpcd again whenever you attach to a new network. If you have an existing lease it should be confirmed quickly.

If you object to typing in "dhclient" or "dhcpcd" everytime, you could automate it with a shell script. It could look something like

```
#!/bin/sh
dhcpcd wlan0 &
wpa_supplicant -d -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
```

dhcpcd will say it is "waiting for carrier" until wpa_supplicant brings up the wireless link.

Comment: I **am** running dhclient (but that could be dhcpcd) whenever I attach to a new network. I want this to be automatic, so I don't have to type "Give me a DHCP address" every time. But not at the cost of asking the DHCP server for a new IP address every second.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a possible script you could use for connecting to a wireless network.